# What healing abilities either scale with stats other than Healing Power, or don't scale at all?

Tags: the-secret-world

Having to mix in +Healing talismans in order to improve my sustainability is a drag. Sadly, most active, and even most passive healing skills scale primarily off of the Healing Power stat. Which of course, I can't get any of if I want to max out my Attack Power or Health (or some combination thereof).

I know of a few abilities that don't require any +Healing to be effective. **Turn the Tables** is the most well known, as it provides a flat, instant, 642 healing at any time. Another option for Blades users is **Point of Harmony**, which provides healing scaled based off of your max Health, for a total of 30% of max HP over 3 seconds.

Are there any other healing abilities that scale based on Health or Attack Power, or which provide high, un-scaled returns for players that are not otherwise built for healing? I'm particularly interested in passives that provide these benefits, but active abilities are, of course, of interest as well.

Comment: I'm curious... are you looking to heal others or just mitigate damage to yourself? I find that the passives on my Sword skills do very well to mitigate damage when I tank. I'll log into the game tonight and get some more detailed information for you :)

Comment: I'm primarily interested in self healing, but if course, abilities that can be used on others are even better! Most of the sword passives, to the best of my knowledge *are* scaled by Healing Power, FWIW. (Which doesn't mean they aren't useful, but they wouldn't be valid answers to this question.)

Answer (score 6):

No guarantee for completeness, but here's what I've found so far:

### Active Abilities

#### Expulsion (Elite) — Blood — Possession

Cast: Instant   Cooldown: 60s

Places an absorb barrier on you that absorbs **100%** of incoming damage and dissipates after absorbing **143** damage. This barrier *scales with Attack Rating* and not with Healing Rating. When the barrier either expires or is spent, it will deal **132** magical damage to all enemies near you.

#### Point of Harmony — Blade — Sharpening the Senses

Cast: 3s   Cooldown: 80s   Channelled: Every 0.5 seconds for 3 seconds.

A channelled heal that heals you for 5% *of your maximum health* each hit.

#### Turn the Tables — Green — Survivalism

Cast: Instant   Cooldown: 35s

A self heal that heals for 642. This value is *not affected by your healing power*.

### Passive Abilities

#### Immortal Spirit — Blade — Technique

*Whenever you penetrate*, you gain a heal over time effect, which heals you 10 every second for 5 seconds.

#### Regeneration — Blade — Technique

"**Martial Discipline**" also gives you a heal over time effect, which heals for 57 every second while it is active.

### Notes

The above passives don't exactly have any "special" scaling (other than Penetration rating), but they are clearly meant for self-healing during combat and as fellow Blade user I can say that **Immortal Spirit** has been very helpful in keeping me alive when soloing. It's meant to be used in combination with a **Penetration** focused build and equipment (be sure to include **Four Seasons** with it's guaranteed penetrating hits).

Including one or two defensive/tanking abilities (especially **Martial Discipline** in combination with **Regeneration**) is also immensely helpful in increasing survivability and lets you live through an "add" that would otherwise mean a visit to the anima well.

Thanks to [tsw-builder.com](http://www.tsw-builder.com) for the raw data.

Comment: This is a great start, but it's definitely missing quite a few, such as Karma.

Comment: Not sure what that scales with, just says "a percentage". What about Anima shot which has a fixed part that scales with healing power and a "percent of damage" part that therefore scales with attack rating - would that be included?

Comment: No, Anima Shot wouldn't count, it's a standard leech effect, and is primarily based on healing power. Karma scales on the max HP of the target healed.